# Why is this not indenting HTML?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id = "topParagraph"><p id = "topParagraph">text </p>

<p id = "paragraph2"> stuff</p></div>
```

I though `<p>` was used to indent. Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zybK/) to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specifcy the `text-indent` style. `p` doesn't automatically indent, it just creates a new paragraph. Try:

```
#topParagraph {
text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Also shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zybK/2/

Answer (score 4):

If you want the text to indent, you need to set the "text-indent" style for the paragraph(s).

In your style sheet you can set

```
p#paragraph2 {
    text-indent: 3em;
}
```

or, for both

```
p {
    text-indent: 3em;
}
```